# Access Items in MainActivity / ContainerActivity from fragments

Tags: android, fragment, floating-action-button

**How can I access my items from the host activity and use it in my fragment?**

**For Example :**

`

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="175dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="238dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

**and I want to access FloatingActionButton and costume it inside a fragment!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is very simple, simply you can write this code inside your fragment**

```
FloatingActionButton fab;
```

**Then find Id:**

```
fab = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

**Using *getActivity()* methode.**

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the above answer. Here is an interface based method. 
1. Create an interface with method A()
2. Initialize interface object in fragment in onCreateView() or onViewCreated() method
3. Implement interface in activity
4. Call A() from fragment to control items in activity or for sending data to activity